# Dive into Python - ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, valueerror

In Chapter 6 of Dive into Python, the author puts the rules for the function that changes singular English nouns to plural ones into a separate txt file:

```
[sxz]$ $ es 
[^aeioudgkprt]h$ $ es 
[^aeiou]y$ y$ ies 
$ $ s
```

And then uses it here:

```
import re

def rules(rules_filename):
    with open(rules_filename) as pattern_file:
        for line in pattern_file:
            pattern, search, replace = line.split(None, 3)
            yield build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace)

def build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace):
        def matches_rule(word):
            return re.search(pattern, word)
        def apply_rule(word):
            return re.sub(search, replace, word)
        return (matches_rule, apply_rule)

def plural(noun, rules_filename='plural.txt'):
        for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules(rules_filename):
                if matches_rule(noun):
                    return apply_rule(noun)
        raise ValueError('no matching rule for {0}'.format(noun))
```

I've created a txt file with the rules for changing singular French nouns to plurals (but used a comma as a separator instead of space):

```
[sxz]$,$,$
au$|\btravail\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bcorail\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bemail\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bvitrail\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\banimal\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bjournal\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bcheval\b|,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bhopital\b,au$|al$|ail,$aux
\bbijou\b|,ou$,oux
\bcaillou\b|,ou$,oux
\bchou\b|,ou$,oux
\bgenou\b|,ou$,oux
\bhibou\b|,ou$,oux
\bjoujou\b|,ou$,oux
\bpou\b,ou$,oux
eu$,$,eux
ou$,ou$,ous
$,$,s
```

And now i'm trying to use this file in the same code as the author did (I did change the name of the file here `def plural(noun, rules_filename='rules.txt'`), but I keep getting a ValueError:

```
File "fr_pl4.py", line 10, in plural
    for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules(rules_filename):
File "fr_pl4.py", line 6, in rules
    pattern, search, replace = line.split(',', 3)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I have also used the rules form the book with the code from the book (you can find them above)... 
And I’m still getting the same error:

```
>>>plural('chat') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File "pl.py", line 10, in plural 
for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules(rules_filename): 
File "pl.py", line 6, in rules 
pattern, search, replace = line.split(None, 3) 
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I called the file just like in the book “plural5-rules.txt”.

I tried to replace comma with a space, but it still doesn't work. Also, my second question is... how can I call this function? I did it like this:

```
>>> from fr_pl4 import plural
>>> plural('chat')
```

A big thank you for answering my question in advance!

**Upd:** So I did as suggested by **Evert**, and this is what I got:

```
>>> plural('chat')
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf830

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pl.py", line 11, in plural
    for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules(rules_filename):
  File "pl.py", line 7, in rules
    pattern, search, replace = line.split(None, 3)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So that's probably what was causing the problem! I used another text editor and it finally worked!!!!

```
>>> from pl import plural
>>> plural('cat')

[sxz]$ $ es

[^aeioudgkprt]h$ $ es

[^aeiou]y$ y$ ies

$ $ s 

'cats'
```

That were the rules form the book. I had to modify the rules for French nouns like so:

```
[sxz]$ $ $
au$ au$ aux
\btravail\b ail$ aux
\bcorail\b ail$ aux
\bemail\b ail$ aux
\bvitrail\b ail$ aux
\banimal\b al$ aux
\bjournal\b al$ aux
\bcheval\b al$ aux
\bhopital\b al$ aux
\bbijou\b ou$ oux
\bcaillou\b ou$ oux
\bchou\b ou$ oux
\bgenou\b ou$ oux
\bhibou\b ou$ oux
\bjoujou\b ou$ oux
\bpou\b ou$ oux
eu$ $ eux
ou$ ou$ ous
$ $ s
```

It all works now, so thank you Evert!!!

Comment: Can you replace the code from the book with the code you're actually using? That's more important than the code it's based on. See [mcve]

Comment: Edit your question, don't put this stuff in comments.

Comment: There's obviously a line with less than two commas. I can't spot it in the input file you've shown, but the easiest way for yourself to debug this, is to put a print function directly before the code line causing the problem, and print the input string (i.e., `line`). I don't spot anything wrong with the code itself.